# Need to learn correct plural and singular

Tags: grammar, grammatical-number

> There are a certain type of toxic people. They're those who won't give you any reason to expect anything from them. But you will still want to expect from them. They're the elusive ones, thousand lights years ahead. And they're precious. You'll find their company enjoyable. Term 'enjoyable' doesn't stand out here. Let's go with 'overwhelming'. 'Overwhelming' in a good way. They are like the Mirror of erised. You can see your desperate desires through them. And none of what you see through them will ever be real.

Is it correct to write there ***are*** a certain type of toxic people?

Comment: Your meaning is off. Something that's toxic refers to something hazardous, poisonous, or unwanted. But you then talk about people who are precious and whose company you enjoy. Those two things do not equate with each other.

Comment: Your question isn't very clear - you might want to edit it. Be sure to show what you've done to try and answer your question on your own. If this is a question about singular/plural usage and verb conjugation, consider if it might be better on https://ell.stackexchange.com/, which is for English language learners.

Comment: The noun phrase for agreement is 'a type', not 'toxic people'.

Answer (score 2):

No, that isn't. The correct one would be as follows;

> There is a certain type of toxic people.

The above is the case when you are talking about a specific / particular type of people. If you meant more than one type of people, here's how you would say;

> There are certain types of toxic people.

Answer (score 0):

It's fine. English doesn't always use logical number agreement, sometimes it uses semantic agreement instead. This is similar to *a number of people are ...*. See [here](https://en.oxforddictionaries.com/explore/number-of-people-is-or-are).

> There is a certain type of toxic people.

is grammatical but it is talking about the *type*, not the people. (I would prefer *a certain type of toxic person*). It is appropriate if you are then going to go on to talk about the type.

> There are a certain type of toxic people.

is saying that the people exist, not that the type exists.